# Amazon Web Services RDB ER_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I keep trying to connect to my database instance here:

> my-test-database.c3j6vph7cyv2.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

But I keep getting getting denied access :\

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my-test-database.c3j6vph7cyv2.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)

I've been trying to find an option to allow remote access for an hour but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Error 10060, at the end, is `WSAETIMEDOUT` -- Connection timed out.  The problem is *not* on the database itself and *not* your credentials.  It is an issue with your security group not allowing you access, or if you are accessing this across the Internet, you didn't configure the instance to be "publicly" (Internet) accessible.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I double checked, its publicly accessibly